# Which of the following statements are correct?

Tags: group-theory

T he order of the smallest possible non trivial group containing elements $x$ and y such that
$x^7=y^2=e$ and $yx=x^4y$ is

(A) $1\space\space$ (B) $2\space\space$ (C) $7\space\space$ (D) $14$

Comment: so , how many elements should it contain,Sir?

Comment: Hint: 7 is prime

Comment: I think B, it can't be A since then it is trivial, but let x=e, y=e, and assume there is another element z(order 2) in the group that is not the identity element, then every equation is trivially satisfied.

Comment: Yes, B is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can just construct it with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ under addition (mod 2) and let $x=0$ and $y=1$.  If you add $0$ seven times you get $0$ and if you add $1$ twice, you get $0$ (mod $2$).  The last one is $$1 + 0 = 0+0+0+0+1 \pmod{2}$$

Not going to find any smaller non-trivial groups than one of order $2$.

Now if you knew the *order* of $x$ were $7$ and the *order* of $y$ were two, then things would be different.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I thought about it.

First, it shouldn't be A, because the group is said to be non-trivial.

If it is B than the non-identity element has even order and you have $x^7=e$ which means that it only works if $x=e$. In this case the relations reduce to $e^7=y^2=e$ and $y=y$ and this is clearly possible. That answers the question.

---

However the wording of the question is somewhat loose. We can let $x=y=e$ so that the relations given are trivially satisfied, and because the question doesn't say that $x,y$ generate the group, we can introduce any other elements we like. Normally we wouldn't do that as it would just make the group bigger - but here we need to make it bigger to meet the "non-trivial" condition. So we can choose $x=y=e, z^2=e$ as an alternative group of order $2$.

Comment: I didn't think of that second possibility and perhaps neither did whoever set the problem! Fortunately it does not affect the correctness of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If we read the question literally, we might assume that $e,x\ne e,y\ne e\in G$, so $|G|\ge2$. This immediately removes **A** and **B**, and we can argue as follows:

It cannot be **A** because this is the trivial identity group.

It cannot be **B** because we have $x=y$ and therefore the statement $x^7=y^2=e$ is inconsistent.

It cannot be **C** because we have $y=e$ and therefore $ex=x^4e$, so $x^3=e$ so $x=e$, which means the group has only $1$ element.

It cannot be **D** because we have $yx=y$, so $x=e$ but this means the group is order 2, but the claim for **D** is that the group is order $14$.

But this doesn't leave any correct answer, so we can assume either $x=e$ and/or $y=e$. This removes **A** and **C** as we have in both cases $x=y=e$, or $D$ as $x=e$.

If we assume $x=e$ both **B** and **D** are correct groups in principle but **D** claims the group is order $14$ whereas it is order $2$. **B** is a correct claim, and indeed the smallest non-trivial group.

Comment: The correct answer is B. Think about it!

Comment: Sorry you are being too mysterious! I can't see a $z$.

Comment: How do you get $x=y$ in case B?

Comment: @celtschk; there are only 2 elements in the group, e and (x=y)

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Wrong in two ways: 1. Nowhere is stated that $x$ or $y$ may not be the identity element. 2. There are groups of order 2 that have more than 2 elements.

Comment: @celtschk  Your second sentence is wrong. By definition, the order of  a group is the number of elements that it contains.  But now I see the source of confusion. The fact that the group contains $x$ and $y$ does not imply that it contains nothing else! I could correctly assert that the room I am sitting in contains a desk and a chair, without implying that it contains nothing else.

Comment: @DerekHolt: OK, I've looked it up in the Wikipedia, and you're indeed right about the meaning of "order" (I consider that a useless definition since we already have a word for it, cardinality, and a confusing one, since "order" is already used for another notion in group theory).